# jQuery Email Validation Fails on Backspace

Tags: jquery, validation, events, email, backspace

```
function validate_email() {
    atsplit = $('input[name=email]').val().split('@');
    dotsplit = atsplit[1].split('.');
    if (atsplit.length == 2 && atsplit[0].length > 0 && dotsplit[dotsplit.length-1].length > 0 && dotsplit[dotsplit.length-2].length > 0) {
        $('#email').html('&#10004;');
        valid_email = true; 
    }
    else {
        $('#email').html('');
        valid_email = false;
    }
}
$('*').live('change click focusout keyup submit', function(){
    validate_email();
});
```

I'm trying to validate an email address. If the email is valid, a check mark is placed in the #email span. Everything works perfectly unless you highlight the input text and press the backspace key (or if you hold the backspace key so that the input is deleted in one keystroke). In these cases, the check mark remains regardless of what events are triggered (click, focusout, etc.). The behavior seems to be the same in all browsers. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try using the keypress event?

Comment: I think this would be covered in the keyup event, but I tried adding it anyways. It didn't seem to make a difference. The strange thing is that after it get's stuck on 'checked', it doesn't come unstuck until the next time you type the @ symbol...

Comment: Add `console.log("Valided")` in the if, see if it is called when you press backspace.

Comment: Also, why don't you use an email regex to validate?

Comment: Sawny, where do I check the console log?

Comment: Sidenote: `.live()` is deprecated. You should consider using [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @danielfaraday: ... in the console ;-) "Tools > Developer Tools" in Chrome, Firebug in Firefox, F12 in IE

Comment: JesseB, this is the first time I've tried email validation. Would a regex be better than what I'm trying?

Comment: Wow, I'm learning all kinds of things.

Comment: Console log: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Comment: Didier, thanks for the note about live(). I've changed to on()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this http://jsfiddle.net/Pq5Ut/ and let me know if that helps you out.  I know I'm not using the same email validation that you are, but I feel it might be what you want.

FYI, the email regex I'm using was just pulled from the jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: Wow, that is some regex! It works great though as long as I use `$('*').live()` to trigger it. When I use `$('*').on()` to trigger, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'.` Why didn't I get this error with `live()`?

Comment: The .on() method was added in jQuery 1.7.  It looks like the version you're using is < 1.7.

Comment: Okay I upgraded to the new jQuery and it works great. Thanks JesseB! I tried to post my final code with all the fixes but I wasn't allowed to (reputation under 100?) so I guess I won't...

Comment: By the way, I also want to validate first names and last names. Any suggestions on regex for this? Or should I just require at least one character to be entered for each?